# Firebase addOnSuccessListener callback running context throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, firebase-storage, coroutine

Suppose I have a repository class that defines a method to retrieve an image from Firebase Storage and defines a success listener that invokes a callback defined from a view model

```
fun getAdImg(imgId: String, callback: (stream: Bitmap?) -> Unit) {
        storage.child(FOLDER).child(imgId+EXTENSION).stream
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                callback(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(it.stream))
                Log.i(TAG, "getAdImg success")
            }
            .addOnCanceledListener {
                Log.e(TAG, "getAdImg canceled")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.e(TAG, "getAdImg failure")
            }

    }
```

The function in the view model that defines the callback and invokes the repository is the following

```
fun loadImage(imgId: String?) {
        imgId?.let { id ->
            if (_img.value == null) {
                viewModelScope.launch (context = IO) {
                    AdvertisementRepository.getInstance().getAdImg(id) { bitmap ->
                        _img.postValue(bitmap)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a couple of questions:

- What's the lifecycle of the listener defined by `addOnSuccessListener` in the repository class?
- What's the scope from which the `callback` function is invoked in the listener?
- When I try to run this code, `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(it.stream)` will throw a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` that seems like an exception due to the context in which the `decodeStream` function is invoked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the lifecycle of the listener defined by addOnSuccessListener in the repository class?

The way you're using it here, it doesn't have a lifecycle.  The callback will persist indefinitely.

> What's the scope from which the callback function is invoked in the listener?

It doesn't have a coroutine scope.  The callback will be invoked on the main thread whenever the result is ready.

> When I try to run this code, `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(it.stream)` will throw a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException that seems like an exception due to the context in which the decodeStream function is invoked

Yes, since the callback is invoked on the main thread, and decodeStream does I/O, you will expect that it will throw an exception if strict mode is enabled to detect I/O on the main thread.  That's why the API documentation for getStream() says:

> Asynchronously downloads the object at this StorageReference via a InputStream. **The InputStream should be read on an OnSuccessListener registered to run on a background thread via addOnSuccessListener(Executor, OnSuccessListener)**

The documentation suggsets that you arrange for the callback to be invoked on a thread other than the main thread using an Executor.  Alternatively, you could use a coroutine, but the API is not Kotlin-aware, so you will need to arrange for that yourself.  There is a library that helps convert Tasks for coroutine usage.

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services

Comment: Suppose I have a repository class whose methods are invoked from multiple view models in different fragments and each method of the repository do async Firebase requests using `addOnSuccessListener` to handle each one. Will the effect of doing this be create a tons of listeners that will run indefinitely? If so, how can I handle this? I can pass the activity instance in the repository and define a lifecycle for them, but what will happen if I will do many requests using that repository?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately and illustrate what isn't working the way you expect.